# What is the TypeScript declaration equivalent of PropTypes.arrayOf?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-props, react-proptypes

I wish to convert PropTypes to Typecript declaration.

I could find the equivalent for most of them, but this one I don't know:

```js
fruits: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOf(['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'dewberry']))
```

My best attempt is:

```js
fruits: any[]
```

But it should be specific for the listed items.

The following ones could be valid and invalid values for property fruits:

```js
// Valid
fruits: ['apple']
fruits: ['cherry', 'dewberry']
// Invalid
fruits: ['my', 'little', 'pony']
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
type fruit = 'apple' | 'banana' | 'cherry' | 'dewberry'

type fruits = fruit[]

const a:fruits = ['apple'] // ok
const b:fruits = ['cherry', 'dewberry'] // ok
const c:fruits = ['my', 'little', 'pony'] // error
```

Try it out on the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAZgTgVwJbCgXigcgIZjAGwkygB8sAjbAO2u2LMwGMALCOOEerAEwgHdybDpgBQI0JFiIUAZ3RTkwANoBdMYwD2VGamwAueIrkYlOPIUwqoAemtQNAaxGbtqcgenBjUUyyGcAGh5+QXZOK1t7JxcdKEYPI3lTAFtArHwUYAsgzDAtcJs7IQ04ESA).